# TypeError: Cannot read property '__expo_module_name__' of undefined, js engine: hermes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I updated my expo and react native app to the latest version and I am facing this issue, I searched on google but didn't find any solution

[image]

Comment: What version was it originally, and what version were you trying to go to?

Comment: old expo SDK version 43.0.0 and react native version 0.66.0 now I upgrade it to expo SDK version 48 and rect native version 0.71.5

Comment: @rameezrahil Did you find a solution?  I am facing the same exact error.  For me, I get the error instantly when trying to import from certain Expo packages:
`import { Audio } from 'expo-av';` or 
`import * as Location from 'expo-location';`

Comment: @ErichCervantez did you solve an issue with import {Audio} from 'expo-av'. I have same issue now

Answer (score 1):

You might be using an already unsupported package. For me it was
`expo-ads-admob`. Considering how popular admob is, you might be using the same.

https://github.com/expo/expo-ads-admob

Answer (score 1):

**Hello everyone!**

I've encountered an error in my Expo application, and I'd like to share my solution with a step-by-step guide. The error I'm facing is related to the use of the `@react-native-voice/voice` package. Interestingly, this code works perfectly fine in a standard React Native environment, but when I attempt to use it in Expo, I encounter the following issue:

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property '__expo_module_name__' of undefined, js engine: hermes
```

Now, let's discuss how to solve this issue. I want to clarify that I managed to implement voice-to-text functionality without ejecting from Expo, thanks to the `expo-dev-client` and profile development. This specific setup can sometimes lead to the error mentioned above.

To resolve this problem, follow these steps:
Update your `eas.json` file to configure it for profile development. You can refer to the official documentation here for a more detailed explanation. [Here's](https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/create-a-build/) what your eas.json should look like for profile development

```js
{
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview2": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      }
    },
    "preview3": {
      "developmentClient": true
    },
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

After updating your `eas.json`, rebuild your project using the following command:

`npx eas build --profile development --platform android`

By following these steps, you should be able to resolve the issue and continue working with Expo without any problems.

Feel free to check the documentation I mentioned above for a more comprehensive understanding of the process. Happy coding!